# cannot start the squid server

Tags: proxy, squid, webmin

When you make start of squid proxy server:

this massage appears (Job for squid.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status squid.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.)

How to solve it?

the output:

-- Logs begin at Mon 2022-10-10 14:56:31 +03. –
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa systemd[1]: Starting Squid Web Proxy Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit squid.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- A start job for unit squid.service has begun execution.
-- The job identifier is 62883.
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa squid[1051704]: 2022/10/13 19:36:40| ACL not found: fac
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa squid[1051704]: 2022/10/13 19:36:40| FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 6174: http_access allow fac
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa squid[1051704]: 2022/10/13 19:36:40| Squid Cache (Version 4.10): Terminated abnormally.
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa squid[1051704]: CPU Usage: 0.010 seconds = 0.000 user + 0.010 sys
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa squid[1051704]: Maximum Resident Size: 57888 KB
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa squid[1051704]: Page faults with physical i/o: 0
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa squid[1051704]: FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 6174: http_access allow fac
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa systemd[1]: squid.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit squid.service has exited.
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa systemd[1]: squid.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- The unit squid.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 13 19:36:40 toj-mgt-uv-fp01.****.com.sa systemd[1]: Failed to start Squid Web Proxy Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit squid.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- A start job for unit squid.service has finished with a failure.
-- The job identifier is 62883 and the job result is failed.

thanks and regards.

Comment: what is the output of `journalctl -xefu squid`. Without giving the error message, it is difficult for the people to help you

Comment: Sorry, where can I find this?

Comment: execute the above command on the system where squid exist to see why it failed

Comment: Thank you for your support. I edited the question and put the output.

Comment: `FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 6174: http_access allow`
what is in that line? You need to have acls to explicitly allow traffic

Comment: In line 6174 nothing, what must I write?